# Mi terminal no ejecuta mi clase en python

Tags: python, vscode, terminal

Estoy aprendiendo de Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO) en Python versión: 3.11.1
hasta que me tope con este problema con la terminal de Python.

codigo de Vs Code:

```
class CuentaBancaria:
     
    def __init__(self, num_cuenta, nombre_titular, balance):
        self.num_cuenta = num_cuenta
        self.nombre_titular = nombre_titular
        self.balance = balance            

    def generar_balance(self):
        print(self.balance)    
                                    
    def depositar(self, monto):
        if monto > 0:
            self.balance += monto

mi_cuenta = CuentaBancaria("243-213-234", "Said Santos", 5600)

mi_cuenta.generar_balance()
```

Terminal:

```
 class CuentaBancaria:
...
...     def __init__(self, num_cuenta, nombre_titular, balance):
...         self.num_cuenta = num_cuenta
...         self.nombre_titular = nombre_titular
...         self.balance = balance
...
>>>     def generar_balance(self):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def generar_balance(self):
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>         print(self.balance)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(self.balance)
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>>     def depositar(self, monto):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def depositar(self, monto):
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>         if monto > 0:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if monto > 0:
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>             self.balance += monto
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    self.balance += monto
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>> mi_cuenta = CuentaBancaria("243-213-234", "Said Santos", 5600)
>>>
>>> mi_cuenta.generar_balance()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'CuentaBancaria' object has no attribute 'generar_balance'
```

No le encuentro sentido a los mensajes de error ya que tengo bien colocadas mis identaciónes,
mi clase espera variables como se ve en la linea 3 y 15 y la variable `mi_cuenta` esta definida como `CuentaBancaria` en la línea 15

Comment: La función `_init_` está mal escrita. Debe ser `__init__`

Comment: es correcto, pero al parecer hay otro error que no estoy encontrando ya que me siguen saliendo los mismos errores

Comment: El problema no está en el código, lo he ejecutado y funciona bien. Podría ser error en el IDE.

Comment: no creo, si es que no hay ningún error de código, debe ser problema de la terminal de python ya que lo ejecute en la terminal de python, fuera de VSCode y da los mismos problemas

Comment: estas seguro que no hay ningún error en el código o no te salta algún error de sintaxis o se identaciones  a ti ?

Comment: por que yo lo mire varias veces y no encuentro nada

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ Lo probé ahí

Comment: si tienes razón funciona bien, será algún erro de instalación de Python, o de la terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al copiar y pegar el código en my editor, me he dado cuenta de que el problema no era del código, ya que se ejecutó todo correctamente sin errores, probablemente se debió a un problema de instalación o configuración de Python o VScode.